# Translating a Sheets document in Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-translate

I'm trying to translate a spreadsheet I've uploaded to Drive and converted to a Sheets. However there is no "Translate" option for me in the Tools menu, as per [this article](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=187189). My Tools menu:

[image: Tools menu]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've only seen that option in a Google Doc, but not a Google Sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula to get text translated:

```
=GoogleTranslate("text", "source language","target language")
```

See reference: [TRANSLATE](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388877)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DocTranslator](https://www.onlinedoctranslator.com). It keeps the document layout, and translates your document in seconds. 
Apparently it uses the Google Translate API as well, so I suppose that would achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this short google apps scripts function that duplicates each sheet in a workbook, and translates the cells. The from and to languages are just function parameters at the moment, but it would be easy to add a prompt and/or use language detection.

```
function duplicatetranslate(inputLang, outputLang) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (index = 0; index < sheets.length; index++) {
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheets[index]);
    var dup = spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
    var cells = dup.getDataRange();
    cells.setFormulaR1C1("=iferror(googletranslate('" + sourceSheetName + "'!" + 
       "R[0]C[0],\"" + inputLang +"\",\"" + outputLang + "\"),\"\")")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google translate to translate a spreadsheet (.xls or xlsx), and also pdf's, word doc's etc.  - But they do not get saved into your Google drive.

http://translate.google.com/?tr=f&hl=en

Select "Choose file", browse for it on your local drive, the click on "Translate".  Saving it out is a copy & paste affair unfortunately though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en-US&u={link-of-page}&sl=auto&tl=en-US
```

where the u parameter (`u={link-of-page}`) you can add the link of your Google Document

Comment: I tried it, with both a Google Sheet and Google Doc, but wasn't successful. Even tried with and without curly brackets. Perhaps you can explain the procedure a bit more?